# Яндекс карты api как сделать draggable: false при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: yandex-maps-api

```js
  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinates, {
      hintContent: '<span class="hint">Меня можно перетащить</span>'
  }, {
      draggable: true,
      iconOffset: [-3, -7],
      preset: 'islands#icon',
  });
```

Не могу понять как сделать смену draggable: true на false при нажатии на кнопку, которую я сам создаю.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить на кнопку event, прослушивающий [isSelected()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ISelectableControl.html#method_detail__isSelected). И в зависимости от состояния кнопки менять опцию **draggable**.
Для [примера с прямоугольниками](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/rectangle) из песочницы Яндекса подойдёт такой код:

```
   var dragButton = new ymaps.control.Button("dragOff");
    myMap.controls.add(dragButton);
    dragButton.events.add("click", function () {
        if (dragButton.isSelected()==0) {
            myGeoObject.options.set("draggable", false)   
        } else {
            myGeoObject.options.set("draggable", true)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Спасибо мне понадобилось только это myPlacemark.options.set('draggable', false);